# Kittens game: what is "Space Paragon"?

Tags: kittens-game

My oil production includes "Space Paragon:" +7489%

What is Space Paragon?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Space Paragon is an attempt to make Hydraulic Fracturers more useful.

Both Hydraulic Fracturers and Oil Wells generate oil. The base oil generation of Hydraulic Fracturers is much higher than that of an Oil Well. The former is also more expensive. This is sensible so far.

However, there are multiple multipliers which can significantly increase oil generation for Oil Well. Before the introduction of Space Paragon in 4.02 or 4.03, these multipliers did not apply to Hydraulic Fracturers. This resulted in Hydraulic Fracturers being almost useless endgame.

Space Paragon fixes this. Most, if not all, of the bonuses to Oil Wells now increase Space Paragon, and thus oil generation from Hydraulic Fracturers.

Some of these bonuses include

1. Solar Revolution Multiplier
2. Reactor Multiplier
3. Magneto Multiplier

I assume the paragon multiplier also helps with space paragon, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from the source, it's an arbitrary measurement of how paragon affect auto-production of space structures.

What I'm certain of, is that there is no special kind of paragon.